# Angular filter service with promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have the following filter:

```
    app.filter("findDivision", function(divisionService) {

    var isWaiting = false;
    var returnValue = null;

    function myFilter(input) {

        var translationValue = "Loading...";
        if(returnValue)
        {
            translationValue = returnValue;
        } else {
            if(isWaiting === false) {
                isWaiting = true;
                divisionService.getDivisionById(input).then(function(data) {
                    console.log("GetTranslation done");
                    returnValue = data[0].name;
                    isWaiting = false;
                });
            }
        }

        return translationValue;
    }

    return myFilter;
});
```

Where the function i call in `divisionService` looks like this:

```
 getDivisionById: function (id) {
    var d = $q.defer();
    $http({
        url: api.getUrl2('division'),
        method: "GET",
        params: {filters: {id: {EQUAL: id}}}
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        d.resolve(data);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        api.handleError(data);
        console.log(data);
        d.reject(data);
    });
    return d.promise
}
```

Sadly the output of this looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? and how i can get the correct value?

Comment: Filters are supposed to be synchronous, you can't use async service in it.

Comment: You could make it work though, in this case you need stateful filter: https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.7/docs/guide/filter In your case just add single line before returning `myFilter.$stateful = true;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon the first calls to the filter, the promise probably hasn't resolved yet, because the HTTP call takes a while to finish. Your filter code will immediately jump to the return statement `return translationValue;`. In this case, the filter returns "Loading...".

Unfortunately, the filter won't automatically re-evaluate the filter until the next digest cycle. Angular has no way of knowing that it should do another digest cycle, because nothing changes (no user interaction or changes to $scope). As an experiment, try to manually trigger a digest cycle by changing the model, e.g. by using an `input` box with `ng-model`. At that moment, you will see the filter will re-evaluate and the output will be shown.

Comment: Would i be able to create a directive instead that then uses the service and updates the text